# According to research

Tags: word-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language

To mean "according to the result of research", can I say "according to a research"? Is it more idiomatic to say, "research says" or "according to the result of research"? Example sentences:

> According to research, some dogs may know you're lying.

> Covid can cause cognitive decline according to research.

Comment: Please note: We would use: the result of research and the result of a search (like via Google). So, your usage is not quite right.

Comment: @lambie Thanks. I forgot "research" is not countable.

Comment: Just correct it. It is still wrong. Also, you do not need to apologize. :)

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have been working with several academic articles this week. To address your question, I opened the first two in my documents directory. I literally invested 15 seconds in this task. My point is that these articles were selected almost at random and with no attempt on my part to skew the outcome.

I noticed these sentences in their respective introductions (I have deleted the footnote stuff):

> 1. Cross-sectional research shows negative associations between body image and active social media engagement (ASME), particularly photo-based ASME.
> 2. Substantial research has demonstrated that exposure to unrealistic appearance deals via mass media is linked to body dissatisfaction.

As you can guess, it is quite common to make the **research** the subject of a clause rather than a part of some participial phrase. This doesn't mean that "according to research" is forbidden. It is simply not the norm—probably because it requires more words than the options I've posted above.

Depending on the field and the journal, sentences like the following are also common:

> Women are more likely than men to use social media to view others’ photos, and ASME is how they typically use social media (Smith, 2014).

That is, neither an author nor some generic "research" is identified as a source in the sentence itself. The (junk in the parentheses) does all the work.

To know the best way to approach all of this, you must have a large sense of what is normal in your field. You should also know what is normal for the journal to which you wish you submit an article.

If you are writing something for school, glance at some articles in a few prestigious journals. Get a feel for what is normal. Imitate that. Or ask your professor.